# Como armazenar em uma variável o número de linhas encontradas a partir de uma consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho um Menu lateral na minha página e quero exibir um texto de alerta para o usuário, indicando quando ele tem novas mensagens e a quantidade delas. Para isso fiz a consulta no BD e ela me retorna corretamente a quantidade de registros baseados na query que montei.

O problema é quando insiro no código, pois não está retornando dado algum.Fiz assim:

```
   if ($usuario->getCodEquipe() == 1 ) {

        $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
        $query = "SELECT count(*)  FROM  FaleConosco WHERE status = '0' ";
        $result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);

        echo "              <hr>\n";
        echo "              <li>\n";

        echo "                  <h3><span class=\"icon-comunicacao\"></span>Comunicação</h3>\n";
        echo "                  <ul>\n";
        echo "                      <li  class=\"btn-voltar\">Voltar</li>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#\">Administrar Notícias</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#\">Moderar Comentários</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#\">QVT</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#\">Fale Conosco";


        if($result != 0)
        {
            echo " - <b>$result Nova(s)</b>";
            mysql_close($dbc);
        }



        echo "                  </a></ul>\n";
        echo "              </li>\n";

    }
```

A intenção é armazenar em uma variável o resultado da consulta, e no if do código comparo o valor e exibo o alerta. Usando a query diretamente no banco, ela funciona e me retorna o número dois, porém neste código não retorna nada. Alguém sabe me dizer o motivo?

Obs: fiz no PHP e MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente está usando uma função obsoleta e descontinuada nas últimas versões do PHP.

Dependendo de qual versão do PHP está a usar é impossível usar o `mysql_query`, assim como impossível usar qualquer função do `mysql_*`.

Para saber o mais informações sobre o `mysql_*`, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql).

**Solução:**

1. Use mysqli_* (recomendado):

   ```
   $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
   $query = "SELECT count(*)  FROM  FaleConosco WHERE status = '0' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   ```

Isso irá usar o mysqli_* ao invés do mysql_*.

2. Repare o `mysql_`:

   ```
   $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
   $query = "SELECT count(*)  FROM  FaleConosco WHERE status = '0' ";
   $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc);
   ```

Isso irá corrigir o parâmetro passado, de maneira invertida no `$result`, [como mencionado pelo @CleitonCardoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142828/15089).

Answer (score 2):

Inverte os parâmetros na chamada da função:

Disso

```
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);
```

Para isso

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc);
```

Não cheguei a testar, mas vê aí.

Answer (score 1):

O resultado é acessado utilizando o método [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-result.php)

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código, mas não tive como testar pois atualizei o PHP em meus servidores e a lib mysql_... não funciona mais... logo, não tenho como garantir que está funcionando, mas acho que dá uma idéia do caminho a seguir... segue código atualizado:

```
 if ($usuario->getCodEquipe() == 1 ) {

        $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nome_banco');
        // utilizai o "as qtd" para identificar o campo por string
        $query = "SELECT count(*) as qtd  FROM  FaleConosco WHERE status = '0' ";
        $result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);

        echo "              <hr>\n";
        echo "              <li>\n";

        echo "                  <h3><span class=\"icon-comunicacao\"></span>Comunicação</h3>\n";
        echo "                  <ul>\n";
        echo "                      <li  class=\"btn-voltar\">Voltar</li>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#">Administrar Notícias</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#">Moderar Comentários</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#">QVT</a></li>\n";
        echo "                      <hr>\n";
        echo "                      <li><a href=\"#">Fale Conosco";

// pega o número de registros convertidos para inteiro na base 10
$num_registros = intval(mysql_result($result,0,'qtd'), 10);
        if($num_registros !== 0){
            echo " - <b>$num_registros Nova(s)</b>";
            mysql_close($dbc);
        }



        echo "                  </a></ul>\n";
        echo "              </li>\n";

    }
```

Espero ter ajudado!